# What is the difference between Isolated Storage Site setting and application settings?

Tags: silverlight, isolatedstorage

Would like to know the difference between Isolated Storage Site setting and application settings? When to use what in the application in Silverlight.

Comment: Also which of these will have longer existence.

Answer (score 1):

There is isolated storage for a site and for the application and the respective settings who built on it.

Site storage is shared among all applications running from the same domain, where application storage is shared only among all applications running from the same uri - which will usually be only one application.

Both exist as long as they are not removed explicitly by the user I believe.

Answer (score 0):

As per MSDN says and on my previous experience:

*SiteSettings are specific to a user, but are shared across applications in the same sub-domain. For example, an application at http://www.contoso.com/site1/application.xap will share SiteSettings with an application at http://www.contoso.com/site2/application.xap. However, SiteSettings for applications at www.contoso.com/ will be isolated from applications at dev.contoso.com/ because they are hosted on different sub-domains.*

So you can use two different XAPs on the same domain but on application you will be isolated from that.